# Setting up OpenProject on OpenShift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, openshift, openproject

I'm trying to install [OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_OpenProject_2_4) on [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) but I'm having difficulties in understanding the process. I've managed to create an `OpenShift` application and `SSH` into the domain, however I don't have permissions to download the zip file / create the folder as in the instructions.

I have to mention that my GIT/Ruby/Openshift knowledge is very limited.

Has anyone tried this before? Can you tell me if it's possible and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to ssh into your gear

$ rhc ssh -a

Then cd into the data dir

$ cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

Wget your file

$ wget https://github.com/opf/openproject/archive/2.4.0.zip

Comment: i ssh'ed into the app from linux but other than that your answer worked great. thanks !

Comment: Do you have download link to 3.0 ? I'm using Openshift V2 and it only supports upto Ruby 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I, despite this issue being so old, I would like to share my efforts. I also wanted to get OpenProject running on OpenShift. My way was to first get an initial POD running with root permissions to set things up with the WebUI and then run the individual services without root permissions.

Details can be found in this Github repository:
https://github.com/jngrb/openproject-openshift